# Link field to node content only with Colorbox

Tags: views, nodes, javascript

I would like to show all "content type A" pop up in Colorbox, with "main content" only. Meaning no header, sidebar or footer.

So In my Drupal 7, I installed Colorbox and Colorbox node modules. And created a Views that list all of the "content type A". Then I added a "Content: Title" field with "link this field to the original piece of content" and "display the content inside of a colorbox" are checked. However, the link did pop up with colorbox but it come with full page, which is including the header, menus, footer and everything else. How can I just show the main content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to admin/config/media/colorbox and at the bottom there is a settings called 'Colorbox Node Integration' **uncheck** `Enable Regions` and save it.
After that colorbox shows only main content of node.

[image]

Comment: yup, that was checked. It changed all those header, main content and footer into individual <div class="region">. It still showing the full page.

Comment: That should be unchecked.

Comment: oh my.... IT"S WORKING!. TY Rupesh :)